# Pull request & Intellij

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I would like to understand how to perform a pull request from within Intellij. I know it sounds tool oriented, but still i think i am missing something that is not necessarily explicitly explained.

I want to contribute to a project to which i don't have write access on github. So shall i first create a fork and then a clone of my fork in my machine, then from there, push my change into it, and do the pull request from that fork online?

Because so far i have cloned the repo, done my changes, commit them locally, then try to do a pull request with intellij, but i get a 403.

So i wonder what is the options i have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So shall i first create a fork and then a clone of my fork in my machine, then from there, push my change into it, and do the pull request from that fork online?

That is the [recommended workflow](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/).

> so far i have cloned the repo, done my changes, commit them locally, then try to do a pull request with intellij

If by "clone the repo", you mean the original repo (instead of your fork), you can [rename that `origin` as `upstream`](https://help.github.com/articles/renaming-a-remote/), and add a new remote '`origin`' to your fork.

```
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin https://github.com/you/yourFork
```